# Grid MVC Compiler Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcgrid.net

I want to know exactly what mistake I have made.

Is that about upgrade or downgrade the assembly? If that's right what and how can I fix it??

When i run my project this msg appear

> Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly 'GridMvc, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

```
<packages>
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Grid.Mvc" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Grid.Mvc.Ajax" version="1.0.31" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Grid.Mvc.DatePicker" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Grid.Mvc.Redux" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jquery.jstree" version="3.3.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.12.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jsTree" version="3.1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

web config

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the referenced System.Web.Mvc.dll under your project's References.
2. Add a new project Reference to System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.1.
3. Click on the newly referenced DLL, and in the properties windows set Copy to Local to True.
4. In your project's web.config file, change the System.Web.Mvc entry to:

> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have fix that with this

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.40804 -Project <your project name>
```

This will automatically update Package Mvc